# InfoPath form not opening in browser while using BCS external content type

Tags: infopath, 2016, bcs, external-content-type, infopath-form

I am using external content type in InfoPath form in SharePoint 2016 and the form doesn't open in browser.

How could it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify which types of form template you have selected, it should be either blank or form library template and from the form option setting select form type as **browser enabled**.

High level steps are as below :

Open up InfoPath 2013 and design a blank form

In the Home Tab, Under the Controls section choose the External Item Picker option under the input sub section and add it to the form

InfoPath will add a new group to the data fields with some properties.

Add the Field to the InfoPath form, right click and pull up the Properties for the external Item Picker

Enter the Namespace of your ECT , Name of the ECT and the System Instance Name(in our case it is CRM) into the required fields. Enter the Display Name of your field, otherwise you would only the see the identifier when you preview the form..

For details refer to the below article :

[Consuming External Content Types(BCS) in InfoPath Forms](https://www.google.com/amp/s/techdhaan.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/consuming-external-content-typesbcs-in-infopath-forms/amp/)